# How does Rust know when to stop iterating over a range with no upper limit?

Tags: loops, rust, iterator, range, infinite-loop

For the [Nth Prime](https://exercism.io/my/tracks/rust#exercise-nth-prime) Rust exercise on [exercism.io](https://exercism.io/), I found that some solutions choose to `filter()` over a range with no upper limit.

Here's an example:

```rust
pub fn nth(n: u32) -> u32 {
    let mut primes = Vec::with_capacity((n as usize) + 1);

    (2..)
        .filter(|candidate| {
            if !primes.iter().any(|i| candidate % i == 0) {
                primes.push(*candidate);
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        })
        .nth(n as usize)
        .unwrap()
}
```

I'm wondering when Rust stops iterating over the range in such a scenario. Does it perhaps iterate until the maximum value of the type, or could it figure out when it can stop iterating by checking code that follows the iterator (e.g. by checking when `.unwrap()` doesn't panic in the example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Iterator`s in Rust are lazily evaluated, so they only "go to infinity" if you call the [`next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) method on them infinitely many times. `Iterator` methods like [`nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) and [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) internally call `next` a finite amount of times, hence there's no issue.

However, if you're iterating over the `Iterator` in a non-terminating loop and the `Iterator` produces some primitive number type then you will eventually hit an overflow when you try to iterator past the max value representable by the type. Example program:

```rust
fn main() {
    for _ in (usize::MAX-1..) {
        println!("counting...");
    }
}
```

Run-time panic:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to add with overflow', /rustc/7eac88abb2e57e752f3302f02be5f3ce3d7adfb4/library/core/src/ops/arith.rs:107:1
```

But that doesn't mean it isn't possible to iterate forever! Some methods like [`cycle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle) allow you to create an infinitely repeating sequence which really will go on for forever until you manually terminate the program:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    
    let mut infinite_123 = a.iter().cycle();
    
    for _ in infinite_123 {
        println!("uh oh, forever loop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that panic on overflow only happens in debug mode. In release mode it will loop forever.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the use of [`Iterator::nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth). This method will call the `next` method on the iterator exactly `n` times, then stop.